# How can I put my own laravel package on github?

Tags: php, laravel, github, laravel-5, package

I developed a Laravel package which is currently located in the vendors folder of my Laravel 5.3 installation.

I am trying to put this package on GitHub so other people can use it. Also I want to be able to sync this package only (not the entire Laravel project) to the GitHub repository so I can commit any changes later.

What steps should I take to put this new package for the first time on GitHub and how can I keep the local project synced up with the version on GitHub?

Comment: Add `composer.json` https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md to your library on github so anyone can add it to their dependencies.

Comment: I already created the json file for my package. But how would I put the files on GitHub? I mean there is got to be a step where I need to provide my credentials for Github and another step to sync up only the package to GitHub not the entire project

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look to this: (You most likely want to create a composer package)

https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/create-composer-package

Answer (score 0):

To put the package on GitHub follow these steps: 
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

To keep the project "synced up" commit and push changes that you make to the Laravel package, and they will show up on GitHub.

`git add .`

`git commit -m "commit message here"`

`git push`

Note: `git add .`  adds all changes.

Use `git add [filename]` to add specific files.

Comment: What about composer?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel works with composer package manager so you have to make a composer package 
from the [Composer Official Documentations](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repository) :

> A repository is a package source. It's a list of packages/versions.
>   Composer will look in all your repositories to find the packages your
>   project requires.
>
> By default only the Packagist repository is registered in Composer.
>   You can add more repositories to your project by declaring them in
>   composer.json.

so all you need is a composer.json which contains your Project files 
 here is a good tutorial for creating your very own packages
[create-composer-package](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/create-composer-package)